# How to retrieve data from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How can I retrieve an array of the data that I want from firestore, given [this Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL89J.png). I tried to retrieve data with the code in the code snippet, however I am faced with the following error: `Invalid document reference. Document references must have even number of segments but user_data/.../run has 3`.

```js
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setUser(user.uid);
    } else {
      console.log("no user found")
    }
  })

  //Retrieve user entries
  const colRef = doc(db, 'user_data', user, "run");
  const q = query(colRef)

  onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      const user_data = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          user_data.push({...doc.data()}) //put the data into an array
      })
      if (bool === false) {
          setArr(user_data);
          setBool(true)
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are using `doc()`, which should be used to get a DocumentReference instance, on a path that returns a CollectionReference instance.

```
const colRef = doc(db, 'user_data', user, "run");
```

The code above attempts to assign the "db/user_data/user/run" CollectionReference instance to colRef, incorrectly using the `doc()` method.
Remember that firestore saves data in a collection-document-subcolletion-document etc. manner. That means `db` should be your database root reference, `user_data` should be a root collection, and `user` a document in the `user_data` collection.

Change your code to correspond to that pattern, like so:

```
const docReference = doc(db, "aRootCollection", "documentId"); // Get the document reference.
const docSnapshot = await getDoc(docReference); // Get a snapshot of the document.
const documentData = docSnapshot.data(); // Get the data of the snapshot. In your case, this would return the "run" array.
```

There is no need to use Query for what you're trying to accomplish.
Make sure you are familiar with `Promises` and/or `async await` and handle all possible exceptions correctly.

Make sure you read the [official Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). It is pretty well-written, with examples.

P.S. Try to be consistent with your quotes for better readability.

Take a look at this data structure. [image: data structure]

```
const aDocmentId = "hH8FfavuIKCwaSQPKmFY"; // The document Id you wish to reference.
const docReference = doc(firestore, `users/${aDocmentId}`); // Getting the Document Reference.
const docReference2 = doc(firestore, "users", "hH8FfavuIKCwaSQPKmFY"); // Same thing but static, with different syntax.
const docSnapShot = await getDoc(docReference); // Get the Document Snapshot.
const docData = docSnapShot.data(); // This will be { name: 'myName', age: 25, rentedMovies: [ 'Burn After Reading', 'Interstellar' ] }
for(const field in docData) { // Loop through all key-value pairs in docData.
   console.log(`${field}: ${docData[field]}`); // Log "Field: value", for every key-value pair.
}
```

The code above will log the following:

```
name: 'myName'
age: 25
rentedMovies: Burn After Reading,Interstellar
```

Comment: Sorry, I think the main issue here is when looking into the data base (it is a linked below my post named Data structure) I have no idea how to retrieve from firestore fields of type map. It gives me the same error despite fixing the reference.

Comment: Given the fact that you have correctly referenced the document and assigned it's data in documentData, as per the example above, accessing the fields of your data structure should be as simple as, for instance, documentData[0].averagepace (=0) or documentData[0]['day'] (=Monday). You can manipulate the array as you please, in plain JavaScript.